# Trouble with inserting new elements into a vector while running a recursional function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, vector, permutation

I have a class where I want to generate all the permutations of the string "123"

so I want the strings "123","321","132" etc

In this class I have defined a 
         vector 
which will hold all these strings which I want to use later...

Here is the recursion that I use in order to find all the permutations:

```
  findPermutations(char *set, int begin, int end){

     int i;
     int range = end - begin;
   if(range == 0) myvE.push_back(set); //notice how I want to update the vector
     else{

    for(i=0;i<range;i++){
        swap(set[begin],set[begin+i]);
        findPermutations(set,begin+1,end);
        swap(set[begin],set[begin+i]);
      }
     }
   }
```

if range is 0 then the set will just have the next permutation. I want to store that permutation in the vector, however in the end my vector is full of "123" strings

I can't understand what's going on here

can someone please help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're adding a pointer to the same string into the vector multiple times, which means that your vector will store multiple pointers to exactly the same string.  Since you're mutating this string inside the recursion, the output will be the same string multiple times.

To fix this, consider either storing copies of the string inside the vector, or switch to a type like atd::string so that adding the string to the vector actually creates a copy for you.

Hope this helps!